# Django taggit - retrieving tags into a template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, django-taggit

I've set up django-taggit and it's working fine, all tags are listed under tags in admin and I can add tags through the admin and in a form.

I'm having real trouble listing the tags in a template (basically I want a long list of all objects with title, url and tags.

Currently I have a method called return tags attached to the model which should return a list of tags for me to iterate over in  the template. Well... that is theory...

Model.py

```
class DefaultResource(models.Model):
#
# This class is the parent class for all resources in the media manager
#
title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
edited_date =  models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False,auto_now=True)
level = models.ManyToManyField(AssoeLevel)
agebracket= models.ManyToManyField(AgeBracket)
pathway= models.ManyToManyField(AssoePathway)
tags = TaggableManager()
slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100,editable=False,blank=True)
updownvotes = RatingField(can_change_vote=True)
views = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20,decimal_places=2,default=0,blank=True)
score = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20,decimal_places=4,default=0,blank=True)
icon = models.CharField(max_length=254,editable=False,blank=True)

def return_tags(self):
    taglist = self.tags.names()
    return taglist
```

view.py

```
def index(request):
context = RequestContext(request)
default_resource_list = DefaultResource.objects.order_by('-score')
context_dict = {'default_resource_list':default_resource_list}
return render_to_response('mediamanager/index.html', context_dict, context)
```

index.html

```
{% for resource in default_resource_list %}

    {% for tag in resource.return_tags %}

    {{ tag }}

    {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

Currently this is returning an empty list.

I've also tried putting the following into the template

```
{% for tag in resource.tags.all %}
{{tag.name}}
{% endfor %}
```

But this also returns an empty list

Answer (score 2):

I am still trying to figure this out, as I want a list of all tags as links to posts that contain that tag. I've only been able to do this by using django-taggit AND django-taggit-templatetags.

Depending on the version of Django you are running try these:

- For earlier versions (before 1.5)

[Django-taggit-templatetags](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-taggit-templatetags)

- For 1.5 or greater (I'm running 1.10 and this worked great)

[Django-taggit-templatetags2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-taggit-templatetags2/1.4.0)

Next I am going to try Django tagging, as the docs are much more complete.

To Jon Clements, I am new to StackOverflow and not sure why my answer was deleted. If you have a better solution to this please advise.

Answer (score 2):

This works on `django-taggit 1.3.0`:

```js
{% for tag in posts.tags.all %}
{{ tag.name }}   
{% endfor %}
```